# Can I use fixed deposit to prove ties to home country?

Tags: visas, schengen

When applying for a Schengen visa, can I use fixed deposit to prove my intention to return after my visit to my friend in Latvia?

Comment: By itself, or in addition to other circumstances (family, property, employment, etc)?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by a "fixed deposit"? Just having money in a bank account proves nothing.

Comment: I am only a graduate and im just 24. I do not have much to prove except ties to my family and my academic pursuit because i still have to go to law school later in the year. I believe a fixed deposit is an investment with a bank that requires time to grow. I wonder if that can show ties to my country apart from having my family and intention to continue my academic pursuit

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Visa Documentation to support 'Intent to Return Home'](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/76097/visa-documentation-to-support-intent-to-return-home-as-a-retired-person) and [How to prove that you have significant ties with family in your home country?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/103826/how-to-prove-that-you-have-significant-ties-with-family-in-your-home-country)

Comment: The 'duplicate' question contains answer, where assets are only one aspect, I doubt it answers this question enough. The linked answer is quite speculative.